# How do I toggle fullscreen mode in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, fullscreen

I have searched and couldn't find anything. I honestly can't believe no one else asked this simple as a rock question. My question is so simple in fact, that I don't even see why I would need to provide code. Anyway is there a function in SwiftUI that I can call in the **AppDelegate** or **button action** to toggle fullscreen mode programmatically?

I also want to know the most efficient way to do this in a action, as well as within the AppDelegate.

Comment: Actually this does not relate anyhow to SwiftUI

Answer (score 3):

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {  

    var window: NSWindow!  

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {  
        self.window.toggleFullScreen(nil)  
        self.window.makeKey()  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Ok Thanks this works, but it suddenly goes to fullscreen mode. Bonus points if you can tell me how to animate into fullscreen mode as if I clicked the green button on the top left of every window. But still thanks.

Comment: @cengizsevimil, It works, but it rather unsatisfyingly just suddenly full screens as soon as the window launches. I will accept once he tells me (and future readers) how to animate into fullscreen

Comment: wait no, it does

Comment: it does go into fullscreen and animate it